# How to enable logs for sitemesh

Tags: java, log4j, logging, sitemesh

Is ther any form to enable logs for sitemesh ? 
I already put this in the log4j configuration but it doesn't work

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>



        <logger name="com.opensymphony">
    <level value="debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.binding">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.transaction">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.orm">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.webflow">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the sitemesh source code, one can easily see that sitemesh doesn't do any form of logging.

Comment: how bad... I think at least they should do something to let us track the error